# Selenium + Python unable to locate element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

Trying to get:

```
<a title="Size 11.0" value="11.0" data-modelsize="11_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.0</a>
```

this element did work at some point but now its returning this error:

> Unable to locate element:
>   /html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/form/div[5]/span[1]/a[11]

It's not in a frame so I know that's not the problem just hit a brick wall too.

Sometimes it throws unable to locate element error and sometimes it will work. Very confusing.

Comment: Show code you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of your code, it's hard to tell. My guess would be that it's a timing issue. When you click the Size button, it takes a fraction of a second to open... my guess is that sometimes you were clicking before it was completely open/available.

When doing something like selecting a size that you will likely reuse a lot, I write functions to handle that so that it's reusable. I wrote `selectSize()` to take care of clicking the Size button, selecting a size, and waiting for the size area to close. I just tested the code below and it's working.

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:256325/sku:CQ2011/");
selectSize("11.0");
```

...and the helper function

```
public static void selectSize(String size)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("pdp_size_select_mask")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[value='" + size + "']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("size_selection_container")));
}
```